# Apache 2.2.2 Refusing To Load/Deload PHP

Tags: php, macos, apache

I just updated the default OS 10.8 installation of PHP to PHP 5.5.1 using homebrew, and I have updated my `httpd.conf` file at `/etc/apache2` but Apache still loads the old, PHP 5.3.15.

I have even uncommented all php5_module lines and it still loads PHP... I am extremely pissed that this refuses to work - it shouldn't even be loading php now, which proves it's not even reading that config file.

I then proceeded to change all other config files in my `/etc/apache2` directory, and it still refuses to load the correct PHP version and continues to load PHP in the first place.

I have then deleted all files in `/etc/apache2` to JUST contain `httpd.conf`, and it still wont change it's behaviour - I am about ready to punch a hole through my screen.

I followed homebrews instructions to the letter, including the obvious apache restart, and I even tried restarting my machine as a last, panic resort.

I have spent the better part of 2 hours trying to "fix" this, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this or what is going on?

---

**Here's my current `httpd.conf`, around the php5_module area**

The 555's were extra precaution, but it's still stubborn as hell.

```
# LoadModule php5_module 55555libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
# LoadModule php5_module    555555/usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

**Here's what I see when I go to `localhost`**

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x
```

**Querying the binary gives:**

```
[ 558 / 58 / 0 ] $ apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec  9 2012 18:57:18
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.3.12
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the value of HTTPD_ROOT, when you run apache2ctl -V

Comment: @Marek $ apachectl -V **[OUTPUT]** -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"

Comment: So you have to look at /usr + SERVER_CONFIG_FILE (again in output of  apache2ctl -V)

Comment: /usr/private/ ... - doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't see the full output when I wrote that. SERVER_CONFIG_FILE starts with / so it's absolute path. /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is the file apache reads. It might be that the start up script sets different path, check that.

Comment: Where do I look for that? I can't see anything obvious in httpd.conf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35729/discussion-between-tsujp-and-marek)

Answer (score 0):

`SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"` - Edit this file, and whatever it includes.

Answer (score 0):

### IMPORTANT STUFF, READ!

Upon a lot of reading through the Apple forums and other resources, it turns out the ability to update to a higher version of PHP, not installed by default on 10.8, is impossible without a third party stack such as [MAMP by Bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp)*[See notes]*.

Based on this, `homebrew` taps that provide repo's to update PHP must be for such third party stacks, or some custom installation of PHP either for compiling and uploading, or with a custom Apache installation somewhere else on the filesystem, not `/etc/apache2/`.

The reason for PHP still preprocessing information was due to Apple's removal of Web Sharing and their subsequent replacements, such as OS X Server, which forces PHP 5.3.15 **and** overrides any PHP module loading in `httpd.conf`.

PHP can only be disabled via the "PHP On or Off" option provided by OS X Server, or some other interface which, I guess, interacts with the same API.

---

### NOTES

Of course, the above is based on chain research and may be incorrect for very specific instances - but I see no evidence to suggest otherwise.

If you are looking for an Apache server running +DefaultPHP you are forced to use a third party stack.

I recommend MAMP by Bitnami because the PHP and other components are up-to-date, more so than other stacks.

It is my guess that if a new, radical version of PHP came out you could interface with it through various `brews` or custom PHP compilation, like you **should** be able to do with the default `/etc/apache2` installation; that is just a guess, however.